# Balance got Reserved while deploying wasm contracts?

Tags: smart-contract, wasm, pallet-contracts, substrate-contracts-node, contracts

i am using **pallet-contracts** in my substrate based chain when i am deploying the wasm smart-contract some balance is getting reserved.How can i stop this i don't want to reserve the balance,Or is there any way i can fix the minimum amount to be reserved?

**impl of pallet_contracts in node runtime**

```
impl pallet_contracts::Config for Runtime {
type Time = Timestamp;
type Randomness = RandomnessCollectiveFlip;
type Currency = Balances;
type Event = Event;
type Call = Call;
type CallFilter = Nothing;
type DepositPerItem = DepositPerItem;
type DepositPerByte = DepositPerByte;
type CallStack = [pallet_contracts::Frame<Self>; 31];
type WeightPrice = pallet_transaction_payment::Pallet<Self>;
type WeightInfo = pallet_contracts::weights::SubstrateWeight<Self>;
type ChainExtension = ();
type DeletionQueueDepth = DeletionQueueDepth;
type DeletionWeightLimit = DeletionWeightLimit;
type Schedule = Schedule;
type AddressGenerator = pallet_contracts::DefaultAddressGenerator;
type ContractAccessWeight = pallet_contracts::DefaultContractAccessWeight<RuntimeBlockWeights>;
type MaxCodeLen = ConstU32<{ 128 * 1024 }>;
type RelaxedMaxCodeLen = ConstU32<{ 256 * 1024 }>;
```

> **as we can see **195,909,000,000,000,000** is getting reserved from the Bob account and **501,000,000,000,000** is reserved in my contract how can i lower the amount or completely
> remove it??**

[image]

Comment: can you send the config of the pallet_contract in the runtime of your node? or where are you deploying the smart contract

Comment: @AlexBean i have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**we can make changes in** `impl pallet_contracts::config for Runtime`

```
type DepositPerItem = DepositPerItem;
type DepositPerByte = DepositPerByte;
```

**if you don't want to reserve any balance then make changes to** `pallets_contracts::config`

```
    type DepositPerItem = ();
    type DepositPerByte = ();
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to your answer:

pallet-contract implements **automatic deposit collection**:

Additionally to the weight, there is also a fee paid for on-chain storage called automatic deposit collection. This additional fee is paid by the caller and is calculated with the price set for each storage item `DepositPerItem` and the price charged for each byte of storage `DepositPerByte`.

The automatic deposit collection can be simplified as follows:

> A caller of a contract pays a deposit to each contract in which new
> storage was created as a result of the executed call. In a similar
> way, a caller gets a refund from all the contracts that the call
> removed storage from.

This mechanism insure that there is no spam from storing on-chain storage. If you set it to 0 anyone can, for free, upload a lot of (wasm blobs) contracts or bloat contract storage without an economic way to avoid it.

Comment: Once the deployed contract is terminated, shouldn't the funds be unreserved and moved to free balance?